# ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install - CDSW

Tags: python, pip, cloudera, cdsw

I am trying to install packages on my cdsw environment.
I have placed the packages in my cd /home/ folder
and I am running below command:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=/home/cdsw/Package/scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl
```

I get below error:
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (maybe you meant "pip install /home/cdsw/Package/scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl"?)

Linux version:
4.4
Python 2: Python 2.7.11
Python 3: Python 3.6.1
Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_211"

How do I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are only passing information to pip of where you want to find the package but not what package to install. find-links is used to pass a location of where your package will be located (and not the package).

To successfully installl you can use:

```
pip install --no-index /home/cdsw/Package/scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl
```

**Edit 1:**
Based on your comments, you also do not have the whl downloaded. So, you can also simply install scipy using the command:

```
pip install scipy
```

or can download a specific whl file from scipy's [github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.7.1)

**Edit 2:**
Since you still are running into the error, and have 2 python versions installed, the pip command might be associated with python2.7. In that case, it is likely that `python3` is the command associated to the python3 installation and `python` is the command associated to the python2 installation. Using the command in the format below will install scipy correctly.

```
python3 -m pip install --no-index /home/cdsw/Package/scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl
```

**Edit 3:**
You have python 3.6.1 installed on your machine, which is not supported by `scipy v1.7.1`. You have 2 options to fix this issue:

1. Upgrade to a newer version of python
2. Install a version of scipy which has python 3.6 support. I looked into the same and found v1.5.4 as the last version with support for python 3.6 support. You can download the whl for the same [here.](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.5.4)

Make sure you are downloading the file containing a file with `cp36` in it, since those will be the files compatible with `python 3.6`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Requirement '/home/cdsw/Package/scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform..... I have tried below package: 1)scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl.crdownload 2)scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl.crdownload 3)scipy-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl

Comment: Is there any proper whl file I can download?

Comment: I have updated my answer @AmyJack. Do let me know if that helps you

Comment: I already have scipy 1.2; i want to upgrade to 1.7.....to do that I need to install a package. We cannot connect to other websites...so I locally download the files then upload onto cdsw and install

Comment: @AmyJack, I have also included a link from where you can download the scipy 1.7.1 whl file.

Comment: I tried all the whl files cp37/38/39 from the link...all result in same error:      pip install --no-index /home/cdsw/Package/scipy-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl
scipy-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_i686.manylinux1_i686.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform......what other method can I try

Comment: @AmyJack, I have added another possible reason, do check if that works out for you

Comment: Still No luck : scipy-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236185/discussion-between-veedata-and-amy-jack).